# java abstract class, Constructor not called in super-class, Why?

Tags: java, class, constructor, abstract

Below is a simple example. I have two abstract classes, `A` and `B`, one concrete class, `C`, which includes the abstract method.

When I create a new `C`, I expected to see the constructors of `A` and `B` being called. Any idea why they are not called?

```
//Q.java
class Q {
    abstract class A {
        A() {
            System.out.println("in A");
        }
        public abstract void sayHi();
    }
    abstract class B extends A {
        B() {
            super();
            System.out.println("in B");
        }
    }
    class C {
        C() {
            super();
            System.out.println("in C");
        }
        public void sayHi() {
            System.out.println("Hi!");
        }
    }

    Q() {
        C Ccc = new C();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Q z = new Q();
    }
}
```

Comment: Class c does not extend either b or a...

you should write `    class c  extends b{ ...`

Comment: c doesn't inherit a or b.  So you haven't really overridden the method

Comment: well c does not extend b or a

Comment: I've renamed your classes to upper-case names, as that's the usual convention. Otherwise it might get confusing to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, we have the super class Object which all classes extend implicitly. so if we have 
`public class A{}`
then it is equivalent to writing 
`public class A extends Object{}` . 
But if you want to extend another class of your own then you have to explicitly mention it as
`public class B extends A{}` 
else java will treat Object as your super class. (NOTE: even it this case Object is a super class to 'B' but this is because it is a super class to 'A' and hence 'B'). So if you don't explicitly mention the 'B extends A' then class B will have Object as its only super class.
More over you dont need mention super() in the sub class constructor. This too is called implicitly.

Answer (score 6):

Because the super class of `c` is `Object`

Further class names start with upper case letters `A,B,C,etc`

If you want to see both `a` and `b` invoked do this:

```
class c extends b
```

Answer (score 3):

Your class `c` doesn't extend class `b` or `a`, so it can't call their constructors using `super()` and calls `Object` constructor instead.

Try this :

```
class c extends b {
    public c(){
        super();
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: that is not technically true.  If `c` was composed of an `a` or a `b` it certainly could invoke either of those constructors.

Comment: Right, I completed the answer :) Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate that you included code.

Answer (score 2):

you should extends the abstract classes from class `c`.

```
class c extends b {
```

Without extending `b` explicitely, it is equivalent to

```
class c extends Object {
```

and, hence call to `super` invokes `Object` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Just make:

```
class c extends b{
```

It will work now.. you have not extended b in c..

Answer (score 1):

`C` and `B` are not related in any way. super class of C is `java.lang.Object` by default

`C` should extend `B` like

```
class C extends B{ .. }
```

In such a case, it will call the super class constructors.

Also, you do not need to call `super()` explicitly as it is implicitly there.